# iphone: applicationDidFinishLaunching method & iOS 4.0+

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I currently have an iPhone application that makes a call to an API to obtain an Access Token.

This function is currently executed in my -applicationDidFinishLaunching method in the AppDelegate.m file.

However, with iOS4.0 and its ability to multitask, does this method get called each time the app is opened?

If not, is there a special delegate method that is called whenever the app is opened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your application is placed in the background, your delegate will receive the `applicationDidEnterBackground` message. If it is opened while still in the background, it will receive the `applicationWillEnterForeground` message, not the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` message.

You can read about the new application lifecycle transitions [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html)